# Remote WebDAV access denied

Tags: iis-7.5, remote-access, webdav

I set up a local folder with WebDAV access (installed IIS, Windows Authentication, Authorization Rules, etc), and browsing to localhost will bring up a virtual directory of the path specified in IIS.  Also, accessing this directory locally via the PC's IP works: for example, `http://192.168.1.100/DRIVENAME` will allow access to the directory.

When I try to access this folder remotely using the external IP address, the dialog box for username/password prompt is displayed, but the admin username/password does not allow access.  For example, browsing to `http://externalip/DRIVENAME` will bring up the username/password prompt, but will not accept the admin credentials.

The designated port in IIS is set to the default 80, firewall rules for both TCP and UDP are set, and the port-forwarding is allowed on the router.

What am I missing?